# Login Client (pGina in Window Vista) with LDAP Server (FDS)

Tags: ldap, fedora

Currently, I have setup my Fedora Directory Server (FDS) and a Windows Vista workstation (using pGina). I created several users in FDS (all under ou=People) initially. As I want to divide my users into 'admin_group' and 'user_group', I created these 2 groups in FDS, thus 'People' group is no longer in use.

My question is under pGina in Window Vista how am I able to identify which group an user belongs to after login? I have different group policy for each group under Windows Vista.

Answer (score 1):

In general when you configure software to use an LDAP server (which FDS is) you would use as the BaseDN:

```
dc=example,dc=com
```

Then you would configure a filter that would select the group the entry has to belong to:

```
ou=admin_group
```

I played a bit with pgina years ago, so am not familiar with it anymore, but you need to look for an entry that allows you to configure an LDAP filter.

To combine multiple filters in an OR, so you either get users in admin_group OR users in user_group do something like:

```
(|(ou=admin_group)(ou=user_group))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Under the configuration of LDAPAuth plugin DLL of pGina, I added (PrePend: uid=, Append: ou=admin_group,dc=localdomain). However, I still have 'user_group'. Btw, do I need to create user group objects under Window Vista so that I can associate group policy for each object?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks aseq! So I should put "Append: (|(ou=admin_group)(ou=user_group), dc=localdomain" in LDAPAuth plugin DLL?

Comment: That sounds about right, but I have no way of verifying. If not that then something quite similar I would say.